# Bootstrap button disabled by default, how can I enable it?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding content to a bootstrap page using `$.get()` from another URL and that is working well except for a close button that displays as if it were disabled.
I've tried `btn-primary` and `btn-info` but I get the same result.
Bootstrap offers a `disabled` keyword but not an `enabled` one.
Here is the html for my button:

`<a class="btn btn-small close"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Close</a>`

My two questions are -- why does it default to being disabled and any suggestions as to how to make it a normal button?
Thanks!

Comment: If you inspect element on it while it is *"disabled"* what classes does it have? What makes you think it is disabled? the way it is styled, or does it not do what it is programmed to do. If both, treat them separately as a disabled class wouldn't stop the functionality.

Comment: Yes, I was not clear on the disabled part. The button actually functions, it just has a very faint look. I figured it out as I explained below on @fp's answer. Bootstrap has a `.close` class that has an `opacity=0.2` setting. So I just changed the name of my class and voila! fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You remove the property:

```
$('#whatever').removeAttr('disabled');
```

and the `disabled` property comes from html.

Comment: Great suggestion but it doesn't work for me.


In this case Bootstrap offers a `.disabled` class that you can use on buttons. And it must be something in Bootstrap that is making it default to a disabled looking state. Mind you, it is only the look that I'm concerned about here because the button works. It's just hard to see. Thanks.

Comment: `$('#whatever').removeClass('disabled');` maybe?

Comment: I figured it out! I named my class `.close` and Bootstrap already has a close class that has a css setting of `opacity=0.2`. Making close a "reserved" class in Bootstrap. So I simply changed the name of my closing button class and solved it. @fp thanks for sticking with me on this.